# Bootsrap 4 как выровнять list-group по центру?

Tags: bootstrap

Как выровнять list-group по центру? По дефолту жмётся к левому краю. 
Bootsrap 4.

```css
    .list-group {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
 <section class="conteiner text-center  ">
            <h1>Заголовок</h1>
            <div class="list-group " style="max-width: 900px; ">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
                    Мы делаем #1
            </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Мы делаем #2
            </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action disabled">Мы делаем #3
            </a>
            </div>

            <p>
                <a href="# " class="btn btn-primary my-2 ">Позвоните нам</a>
                <a href="# " class="btn btn-secondary my-2 ">Напишите нам</a>
            </p>

        </section>
```

Comment: Пример кода, стиля или страницы в студию!

Answer (score 2):

`.list-group` задать `margin: auto;`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  
  
   <section class="conteiner text-center  ">
     <h1>Заголовок</h1>
     <div class="list-group mx-auto w-100" style="max-width: 900px; ">
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
         Мы делаем #1
       </a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Мы делаем #2
       </a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action disabled">Мы делаем #3
       </a>
     </div>

     <p>
       <a href="# " class="btn btn-primary my-2 ">Позвоните нам</a>
       <a href="# " class="btn btn-secondary my-2 ">Напишите нам</a>
     </p>

  </section>
```

Comment: Еще вместо добавления отступов в стилях можно в `.list-group` добавить класс `mx-auto`. Делает тоже самое.

Comment: @AntonMironov, точно! Забыла)

Answer (score 0):

Через `text-align:center`, ну и bootstrap есть классы `text-center`(только 3?) и `text-sm-center`, `text-md-center`, `text-lg-center`, `text-xl-center` (только 4?)

```css
.list-group {
    text-align:center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="conteiner text-center  ">
            <h1>Заголовок</h1>
            <div class="list-group " style="max-width: 900px; ">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
                    Мы делаем #1
            </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Мы делаем #2
            </a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action disabled">Мы делаем #3
            </a>
            </div>

            <p>
                <a href="# " class="btn btn-primary my-2 ">Позвоните нам</a>
                <a href="# " class="btn btn-secondary my-2 ">Напишите нам</a>
            </p>

        </section>
```

Comment: Обёртка <section> уже имеет класс 'text-center', но это влияет только на текст внутри, а не на div

Comment: @Александр, ага - не заметил. Ну а что мешает тогда добавить этот класс в div? Нет под рукой boostrap 4 попробовать.

Answer (score -1):

*Решение:*

добавить в `.list-group {margin: 0 auto;}`